# It it wise to combine CSS files into minified "chunks" across different sections of a website?

Tags: css, performance, optimization, minify

Let's say that you run a very large eCommerce website with millions of page views per day.

Obviously you want to minify and combine your css files to reduce requests, but do you really want to combine the entire site into one file? The benefit is that once that large css file gets cached the rest of the pages will run quickly, but that first file is a beast. And you most likely have hundreds of lines of unused css.

Would it be better to break it into chunks so that you get something like:

Global and Homepage

Global and ProductsCheckout

Global and Features on extra features / info pages

Sure you need to load 3 different files but those files are smaller. The homeapge loads quickly, and you may never need the features files if you go straight to checkout.

Comment: Typically large scale sites use something along the lines of SASS or LESS which takes all the HTTP requests and combines them into one, so it doesn't matter if there's 6 CSS files or 1. If you're not doing something along those lines you'll want to only have 1 CSS file, in my opinion. You should re think your CSS if you have hundreds of lines that aren't being using at least majority of the time.

Comment: All of the css is used somewhere on the site, but not all of the css is used on any single page. So it seems like a mistake to combine everything into one file. I don't think 1 file is the most intelligent strategy.

Comment: For a live site it's smarter to have one CSS file, you want as minimal HTTP requests as possible. HTTP requests take longer than processing a few hundred characters. If you have a large scale application that's module based and you have a CSS file for each module then use a pre-processor like I said to have the end result as 1 HTTP request for all your CSS files. Don't believe me do some testing for yourself, load a page and check how long each file took to load and then put all the CSS in one file and load it and you'll see the time to load that file is less than all the other ones combined.

Comment: Yes I agree that it's wise to combine css files to reduce requests. But if you have a very large site do you really need to load everything on the homepage for instance? If so Google is going to ding you for unused css. LESS doesn't improve performance.

Comment: What are the approximate sizes of the one minified CSS file, and/or the "chunks" that you have in mind? 2K? 20K? 200K? The low-hanging fruit would be to streamline/prune your existing CSS.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that it is wise to break out the css files into different sections and load 2 css files per page depending on the section.

Here is an example from CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/

```
Global = main.css + grid.css + typography.css + buttons.css + print.css
Site section A = tabs.css + editor.css
Site section B = forms.css + video.css + details.css
```

This system helps reduce the amount of unused CSS loaded onto each page, takes advantage of caching, and ensures whichever page the visitor goes to first will load quickly.